# Java user library causes "Fatal error"

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime-error, slick2d

I wanted to import my Java project I am creating with Eclipse and the Slick2D library to my MacBook.
I installed Eclipse for my MacBook (64 bit) and also all needed Java Runtimes.
I imported my Project sucessfully and added the Slick2D library.
Everything is set up exactly like my environment on Windows.

But when I try to run my project this error appears:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000001052a91af, pid=1543, tid=7683

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_20-b26) (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.20-b23 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x4261af]  Klass::is_subtype_of(Klass*) const+0x7

Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try      "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
```

I don't know what to do. I tried everything.
Tried Java 1.6 to 1.8
Changed the compiler
reinstalled Eclipse
added the library several times

I would be very thankful if someone can help me! :)

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you need to run `ulimit -c unlimited`

Will enable core dumps, and it will be placed in /cores/ as core.PID

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add a few more file paths for the library. The set up is a bit different if you use a mac I guess.